# Best way to manage exception in package

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, raise

I have a package with a several procedures and functions, the procedures are called from an external program and in turn they call functions.

Where is the best way to manage a Exception?

For example, Prog1 call Proc1 and Proc1 call the Funct1, if in function I have an exception ("TOO MANY ROW" or "NO DATA FOUND"), which is the best way to raise a specific customized message and return immediatally to Prog1.

In this moment I have this

```
PROCEDURE_1
BEGIN
   *code*
   CALL FUNCTION_1
   *code*
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO DATA FOUND THEN
      *print customized message*
      RETURN;
END;

   
FUNCTION_1
BEGIN
   *code*
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO DATA FOUND THEN
     RAISE;
END;
```

It is the best way?

Regards,
Marco

Comment: There is no point in `when  no data found then raise;` as that is what it will do anyway. It would be cleaner to have no exception handling at all in the function. In the procedure, what do you want *"print customized message"* to do? If you want the caller to know that it failed, that needs to be an actual exception using [raise_application_error](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-error-handling.html#GUID-48F88C61-8CE9-4821-91CB-48A8F1BC09E1).

Comment: I need to create a customized message in JSON format.
I tried with a  raise_application_error but message are not printed in output

Comment: "There is no point in when  no data found then raise; as that is what it will do anyway."
Yes, it's ok, but if the exception is in function, the procedure continue until the end, instead I need the procedure to end for any errors.

Comment: Could the caller detect that the procedure failed, and process the exception by replacing the error message with a customer message in JSON format? Or, have the procedure pass back a status via an OUT parameter, but then the procedure always reports successful completion and the caller has to examine the message text to know whether it actually succeeded or not.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *but if the exception is in function, the procedure continue until the end, instead I need the procedure to end for any errors*. If the function fails with an unhandled exception, the procedure will fail right there.

Comment: I try to explain myself better.
I need do return to called program a output in JSON format.
A format for correct outpur and different format for procedure errors.
If the function go in error I need to intercept this error in order to format output n correct JSON format.

Comment: If i have "unhandled exception", the procedure abort but the message is in oracle standard and the called program not read this format.
I Used the raise_application_error in the exception, this work but print also the sqlcode before the customized message.
For exemple:
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, '{"step": "' || step || '", "message" : "' || SQLERRM || '"}"', false);

Print
ORA-20001: {"step": "Search with field", "message" : "ORA-00905: parola chiave mancante"}"

Comment: I know that from function I can return an error code to the procedure and manage that, but I wanted to understand if there is a faster way that interrupts the whole procedure when an error as intercepted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233092/discussion-between-william-robertson-and-sirlancillotto).

Answer (score 1):

Ideally a procedure would be allowed to fail with an exception and error stack if something went totally wrong, but then the difference between a fatal error and an expected condition will vary depending on the business logic you are implementing, so it's hard to say what should happen in your particular case.

If the agreed interface is that the procedure should return a formatted message, and that message may include expected business conditions such as a product being out of stock, then you can handle that within the procedure using something like this (nonsense pseudocode to illustrate approach only):

```
create or replace procedure procedure_1
    ( p_result_message out varchar2 )
as
    somevar number;
begin
    do_stuff('fruit','cake');
    
    begin
        somevar := function_1('bananas');
    exception
        when no_data_found then
            p_result_message := 'No kittens are available for this mission.';
            return;
    end;

    p_result_message := 'Cake is available in aisle 3';
exception 
    when something_else then
        p_result_message := 'Self-destruct sequence initiated.';
end;
```

(For a more purist approach you might prefer to rearrange the code so that it always reaches the end with a value for `p_result_message`, rather than quitting partway through if some condition pops up.)

Now you have a way to handle whatever exceptions might reasonably arise in `function_1`, without any special handling within the function itself.

You could also have the function raise an exception defined in a package, although then you lose the ability to define a diagnostic error message at the point of failure, and in my experience this just tends to complicate things. But to illustrate:

```
create or replace package starfleet
as
    shield_failure exception;
    warp_core_malfunction exception;

    pragma exception_init(shield_failure, -20998);
    pragma exception_init(warp_core_malfunction, -20999);

    procedure check_status
        ( status_message out varchar2 );

    function status
        return number;

end starfleet;
```

```
create or replace package body starfleet as

    function status
        return number
    is
        status_ind number;
    begin
        select 1 into status_ind from dual where 1=2;  -- fails with NDF
        return status_ind;
    exception
        when no_data_found then raise shield_failure;
    end status;

    procedure check_status
        ( status_message out varchar2 )
    is
        status_ind number;
    begin
        status_ind := status();
        status_message := 'Everything is fine';
    exception
        when warp_core_malfunction then status_message := 'Abandon ship';
        when shield_failure then status_message := 'Increase power to shields';
    end check_status;

end starfleet;
```

Now, the `status()` function can raise exceptions defined in the package (or any other package for that matter), and procedure `check_status` can catch it and decide how to handle it.

Example of calling it from SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> var status_message varchar2(100)
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2      starfleet.check_status(:status_message);
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


STATUS_MESSAGE
-------------------------
Increase power to shields
```